# How to aggregate data into ranges (bucketize)?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like

```
+---------------+------+
|id             | value|
+---------------+------+
|               1|118.0|
|               2|109.0|
|               3|113.0|
|               4| 82.0|
|               5| 60.0|
|               6|111.0|
|               7|107.0|
|               8| 84.0|
|               9| 91.0|
|              10|118.0|
+---------------+------+
```

ans would like aggregate or bin the values to a range `0,10,20,30,40,...80,90,100,110,120`how can I perform this in SQL or more specific spark sql?

Currently I have a lateral view join with the range but this seems rather clumsy / inefficient.

The quantile discretized is not really what I want, rather a `CUT` with this range.

## edit

https://github.com/collectivemedia/spark-ext/blob/master/sparkext-mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/Binning.scala would perform dynamic bins, but I would rather need this specified range.

Comment: `org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Bucketizer` takes an explicitly provided array of split points. You should be able to group on the output column then.

Comment: I think the proposed solution is simpler / probably more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "GROUP BY" with this

```
SELECT id, (value DIV 10)*10 FROM table_name ;
```

The following would be using the Dataset API for Scala:

```
df.select(('value divide 10).cast("int")*10)
```

Answer (score 15):

In the general case, static binning can be performed using [org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Bucketizer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Bucketizer):

```scala
val df = Seq(
  (1, 118.0), (2, 109.0), (3, 113.0), (4, 82.0), (5, 60.0),
  (6, 111.0), (7, 107.0), (8,  84.0), (9, 91.0), (10, 118.0)
).toDF("id", "value")

val splits = (0 to 12).map(_ * 10.0).toArray

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Bucketizer
val bucketizer = new Bucketizer()
  .setInputCol("value")
  .setOutputCol("bucket")
  .setSplits(splits)

val bucketed = bucketizer.transform(df)

val solution = bucketed.groupBy($"bucket").agg(count($"id") as "count")
```

Result:

```
scala> solution.show
+------+-----+
|bucket|count|
+------+-----+
|   8.0|    2|
|  11.0|    4|
|  10.0|    2|
|   6.0|    1|
|   9.0|    1|
+------+-----+
```

The bucketizer throws errors when values lie outside the defined bins. It is possible to define split points as `Double.NegativeInfinity` or `Double.PositiveInfinity` to capture outliers.

`Bucketizer` is designed to work efficiently with arbitrary splits by performing binary search of the right bucket. In the case of regular bins like yours, one can simply do something like:

```scala
val binned = df.withColumn("bucket", (($"value" - bin_min) / bin_width) cast "int")
```

where `bin_min` and `bin_width` are the left interval of the minimum bin and the bin width, respectively.

Comment: But assuming a bucket would be empty the grouping will return no results as well. So if I wanted to see a list of all the buckets (and the empty ones with a count of 0) can this be performed without a join?

Comment: Performing a join with the range after the binning should be pretty efficient.