# Mapping different intervals of values of a column into integers

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe in Spark:

```
customer  |   age
--------------------
    A         25
    B         17
    C         8
```

were both customer and age column is of type string.

So,

- if `(0>=age<=10)` then I want to map it to `0`
- if `(11>=age<=20)` then I want to map it to `1`
- if `(21>=age<=30)` then I want to map it to `2`

Such that the new data frame becomes:

```
customer_new  |   age_new
--------------------
    A         2    
    B         1    
    C         0
```

Here in the new data frame `customer_new` is of type `String` and `age_new` is of type `Integer`.

Comment: you can use withcolumn to create the condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spark sql - aggregate data frame into a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361466/spark-sql-aggregate-data-frame-into-a-range)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withColumn` with multiple `when` function to give your conditions. Try the below code,

```
df.withColumn("customer_new", $"customer")
  .withColumn("age_new",
    when($"age" >= 0 && $"age" <= 10, 0).
      when($"age" >= 11 && $"age" <= 20, 1).
      when($"age" >= 21 && $"age" <= 30, 2)).
  select("customer_new", "age_new").show()
```

It will give you below output

```
+------------+-------+
|customer_new|age_new|
+------------+-------+
|           A|      2|
|           B|      1|
|           C|      0|
+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score -1):

The first step is to convert the column type to double.

```
val df = Seq(("a", "25"), ("b", "17"), ("c", "8")).toDF("customer", "age")
  .withColumn("age", $"age".cast(DoubleType))
```

Then, in the case where you only have a few conditions, it is possible to use `when` and `otherwise`. For example, using your input data and conditions:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("age_new", 
  when($"age" <= 10, 0.0).
  when($"age" <= 20, 1.0).
  when($"age" <= 30, 2.0).
  otherwise(3.0))
```

---

If there are many conditions, then using `when` will get annoying. In this case, [`Bucketizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-features.html#bucketizer) is a good alternative:

```
val splits = Array(0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0)
val bucketizer = new Bucketizer().setInputCol("age").setOutputCol("age_new").setSplits(splits)
val df3 = bucketizer.transform(df)
```

The output is the same in both cases (the `age` column can be removed by using `select` or `drop`):

```
+--------+----+-------+
|customer| age|age_new|
+--------+----+-------+
|       a|25.0|    2.0|
|       b|17.0|    1.0|
|       c| 8.0|    0.0|
+--------+----+-------+
```

Answer (score -1):

It is always advisable to *use an inbuilt functions* as much as possible. Since when function has already been advised by others you can try with map function as

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
df.map(row => {
  val age = row.getAs[String]("age").trim.toInt
  (row.getAs[String]("customer"), if(age >= 0 && age <= 10) "0" else if(age >= 11 && age <= 20) "1" else if(age >= 21 && age <= 30) "2" else null)
})
  .toDF("customer_new", "age_new")
```

which should give you

```
+------------+-------+
|customer_new|age_new|
+------------+-------+
|A           |2      |
|B           |1      |
|C           |0      |
+------------+-------+
```