# How to group by distribution in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am looking for a way to group by a column(int values) based on distributions.For e.g.:

Df =

```
col1  col2
1a      10
2a      120 
3a      3 
4a      10000 
5a      10
```

I am trying to get distributions like (0, 1, 5, 10, 50 ,100, 10000):

```
distribution(lesser than or equal)           count
0                                               0
1                                               0
5                                               1
10                                              2
50                                              3
100                                             3
10000                                           5
```

Is there a easy a way to do this with any pre-defined math functions in Spark ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spark sql - aggregate data frame into a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361466/spark-sql-aggregate-data-frame-into-a-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in first place, we could compute the percentiles of your target column. For example, let's say we compute 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95, 99, 100 quantiles.

```
val df = Seq(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 15, 16, 20, 200, 201, 205).toDF
val quantiles = List(0.01, 0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90, 0.95, 0.99)
val quantsGenerator = for {
    a <- quantiles
  } yield callUDF("percentile_approx", col("value"), lit(a)).as("q" + a.toString)
val quantilesComputed = df.agg(count("*").as("count"), quantsGenerator: _*).drop("count")
```

So in this first snippet, I initialize my DF and quantiles list. For each quantile, I create a column which will be the computation of the percentile on the column. My variable *quantsGenerator* contains the expression of each column that I will apply in the agg function.

The agg function is coded in a way in Spark Source code that you need, to have first a single column (so here I use **count(" * ")**) and then you can give a varargs to the **agg** function which here will be our quantsGenerator. The count(" * ") is useless, just for us to be able to give a varargs to the function **agg**. So you can drop it later.

Once you have this we can generate a final dataframe which will be "La fonction de répartition" as we would call it in French :D

```
val quantsAsArrayDouble = quantilesComputed.collect.map(x => x.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]).flatten
val whenFunctions = quantsAsArrayDouble.map(x => sum(when(col("value") <= x.toDouble, 1)).as("<=" + x.toString))
val finalDf = df.agg(count(lit(1)).as("count"), whenFunctions: _*).drop("count")
```

Again this count(" * ")... Oh no ! count(lit(1)), it's exactly the same. It's interpreted as count(" * ") and is useful in our case to vararg the whenFunctions... grrrr

And in the end, you obtain something that you might want.

```
scala> df.agg(count("*"),c:_*).show
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|<=1.0|<=1.0|<=1.0|<=5.0|<=10.0|<=16.0|<=201.0|<=205.0|<=205.0|<=205.0|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    2|    2|    2|    7|    10|    15|     18|     19|     19|     19|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Multiple same values are recurrent, because I haven't enough data. But I'm pretty sure, this will work well with a lot a data in your case. You can choose the percentiles you want by modifying the first List.

Good luck

PS : I just saw, as a previous post got shared, that there exists the Bucketizer Object in Spark. Yeaaah, this might be more efficient than my technic x) My bad !
Have fun with Spark